# RenderTransform without affecting children possibly Inverse

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm resizing a canvas with touch events as follows:

```
e.Handled = true;
var transformation = MyCanvas.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
var matrix = transformation == null ? Matrix.Identity :transformation.Matrix;

matrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
               e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
               e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

MyCanvas.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
```

The canvas has several child canvasses. I don't want to resize them and in fact need them to go smaller. So looked at RenderTransform.Inverse but am not having any joy.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the child canvasses when you resize the parent one? Do you want them to move to keep their relative positions or just keep the same absolute positions?

Comment: They need to move to keep relative but not resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a custom canvas** by inheriting from [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) with

1. A new dependency property: NonInheritableScale
2. A binding between bind the transform's scale to the NonInhertiableScale property
3. overrides of the MeasureOverride() and ArrangeOverride() methods,
   so that the take 1.0/NonInhertiableScale.X and 1.0/NonInhertiableScale.Y into account during the layout.

Here is an article on [creating custom WPF panels](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) that might help you (a search result, haven't read it).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT after reading the comment below**

In that case of a chart you might want to redraw the chart with different axis ranges. A RenderTransform might be not accurate enough and indeed you will have to scale back everything else (axis, labels, gridlines,...)

**previous answer, still valid**

You will have to iterate through the child canvases and scale them individually. As far as I know there is no build in support for what you want.

You will have to apply both the inverse scale transformation to negate the parent's resize and a scale transformation that will make them smaller.

Post the code you are using to get more detailed help and or feedback.

Comment: Thanks Erno, I'll give that a go. I've create a sort of scatter chart and on zooming want to increase the gap between them for legibility.

Comment: Ah, in that case you might want to redraw the chart with different axis ranges. A RenderTransform might be not accurate enough and indeed you will have to scale back everything else (axis, labels, gridlines,...)

Comment: Yeah it's a very rough chart on a Pixelsense device so only has a single Y axis which is basically 0 (above positive/below negative)

Comment: Went with this solution although I have no doubt that Danny Varod's solution below will also work.